# [ INFO] [1345647384.436612487]: Still waiting on map

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, turtlebot, turtlebot-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find turtlebot_navigation`/nav_rviz.vcg

When I ran this on my turtlebot, as directed [here](http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM), the turtlebot kept repeating "Still waiting on map...". I then continued, and started rviz, with the command given on the webpage. When it started, the rviz screen was black, and no map was being shown. I tried teleoping it around the room to see if I could pick something up, but it still remained black. Any ideas on what the problem might be, or how to make a map using my turtlebot? Thanks!

---

Also, when i try to run

roslaunch turtlebot_calibration calibrate.launch

it says "Still waiting for scan"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42037/%5B-info%5D-%5B1345647384.436612487%5D:-still-waiting-on-map.../) by [buma676](https://answers.ros.org/users/2990/buma676/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2012-08-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

I C the Q is approx a month old, hope u have figured it out.

I was following the same tutorial, but for simulation (later I saw http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Map%20in%20TurtleBot%20Simulator),

But everything was exactly same except one parameter missing in tutlebot_gazebo/launch/robot.launch

I only needed to add :

```
<param name="output_frame" value="odom"/>
```

in the odometry estimator i.e., in the tag:-

```
 <node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf">
```

so now this node, in robot.launch looks like:-

```
  <!-- The odometry estimator -->

  <node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf">
    <param name="freq" value="30.0"/>
    <param name="sensor_timeout" value="1.0"/>
    <param name="publish_tf" value="true"/>
    <param name="odom_used" value="true"/>
    <param name="imu_used" value="false"/>
    <param name="vo_used" value="false"/>
    <param name="output_frame" value="odom"/>     <!-- This is not present in tutrtlebot_gazebo's robot.launch -->
  </node>
```

Only with this modification I am now able to make the map correctly.

Hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) with karma: 339 on 2012-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0